# Rails: Can not mappings type: completion (Gem: elasticsearch-model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Here is my ActiveRecord definition

```
  settings index: { number_of_shards: 1, number_of_replicas: 0 } do
    mappings  do
      indexes :cas, type: 'string', index: "not_analyzed", analyzer: 'snowball'
      indexes :names, type: 'string', analyzer: 'snowball'
      indexes :names_cn, type: 'string', analyzer: 'ik_max_word'
      indexes :suggest, type: 'completion', analyzer: 'snowball'
      indexes :suggest_cn, type: 'completion', analyzer: 'ik_max_word'
    end
  end

  def as_indexed_json(options = {})
    {
      cas: self.cas.to_s.strip,
      names: self.suggests,
      names_cn: self.suggests_cn,
      suggest: { input: self.suggests },
      suggest_cn: { input: self.chinese_keywords }
    }
  end
```

And this is what the elasticsearch server shows to me

```
{
  "something-development": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "chemicals": {
        "properties": {
          "cas": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "names": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "names_cn": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "suggest": {
            "properties": {
              "input": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          },
          "suggest_cn": {
            "properties": {
              "input": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "creation_date": "1470383173607",
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "a8ONu0WSRGuImjLRU6ddVg",
        "version": {
          "created": "2030499"
        }
      }
    },
    "warmers": {}
  }
}
```

And I suppose that the suggest & the suggest_cn item should acts like this : type completion

```
suggest": {
  "type": "completion",
  "analyzer": "snowball",
  "payloads": false,
  "preserve_separators": true,
  "preserve_position_increments": true,
  "max_input_length": 50
}
```

Maybe I have some problems in understanding this . Anybody do helps (best wishes)

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-rails/issues/612 and I also have an issue here .

Answer (score 0):

Use `Chemical.__elasticsearch__.create_index! force: true`

Instead of `Chemical.__elasticsearch__.client.indices.create index: Chemical.index_name`